# Python / Pandas conditional new column ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I wish to add a new column to an existing DataFrame and set `df.TaxStatus` to True or False based on the value of `df.Public` (1|2). I see others creating a new column using `Numpy.where()`, but I get a ValueError.

```
df['TaxStatus'] = np.where(df.Public == 1, True, np.where(df.Public == 2, False))
```

This would appear to work, except for the ValueError: `either both or neither of x and y should be given`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply by saying:

```
df['TaxStatus'] = df.Public == 1
```

The expression `df.Public == 1` returns a Series of True/False values that you can assign to the new column. No need for `np.where()`

Comment: but why does the np.where() cause an ValueError when I have both conditional (true/false) defined?

Comment: It means you have to give the values both for when the comparison is True and False. So if you insist on using `np.where`, you can say: `df['TaxStatus'] = np.where(df.Public == 1, True, False)`

Comment: yes, that is what I needed, conditional True/False for one column to update another new column. thanks